# Determine what object properties a function accessed

Tags: javascript

I have an arbitrarily deep object like this:

```
const objToAccess = {
  id: 1,
  name: {
    first: 'Foo',
    last: 'Bar'
  },
  address: {
    street: {
      name: '987 Walker',
      roadType: 'Ave'
    },
    zip: '12345'
  }
};
```

I call a function that takes the above `objToAccess` as a param. EDIT: This function is a black box. I don't know what it looks like and can't edit it. For example:

```
const accessFn = objToAccess => {
  const a = objToAccess.id;
  const b = objToAccess.name.first;
  const c = objToAccess.address;
};
```

After that function is called, I want to know which properties were accessed. Here's the kicker: **If a nested object was accessed, I want to flag all children as being accessed, too.** For example, after running the above code, I would like a result that looks like this:

```
const propsAccessed = {
  id: true,
  name: {
    first: true,
    last: false
  },
  address: {
    street: {
      name: true,
      roadType: true
    },
    zip: true
  }
};
```

My naive attempt is to created the `propsAccessed` object & set everything to false, and then use getters (below). But, I can't figure out how to use them in such a way that flags all children if just the parent object is accessed. Any ideas would be great!

```
const gettedReturnedMutation = {
  get id() {
    propsAccessed.id = true;
  },
  get name() {
    // TODO if just address is accessed, recursively flag all children as true
    return {
      get first() {
        propsAccessed.name.first = true;
      },
      get last() {
        propsAccessed.name.last = true;
      }
    }
  },
  get address() {
    // TODO if just address is accessed, recursively flag all children as true
    return {
      get street() {
        return {
          get name() {
            propsAccessed.address.street.name = true;
          },
          get roadType() {
            propsAccessed.address.street.roadType = true;
          }
        }
      },
      get zip() {
        propsAccessed.address.zip = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the use case? Reads a bit like an XY problem ...

Comment: Ultimately, i want to remove `false` items from the object. Realistically, the object is an AST.

Comment: You could access with your own function `access(obj, 'path')` and perhaps delete the path, that will get rid of children. Not sure why you need to flag children if the parent is flagged and needs to be removed anyway

Comment: the `accessFn` is a blackbox

Comment: That's a good thing.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the suggestion. Could you please post an example?

Comment: Why is `propsAccessed.name.last` still `false` after the function accessed `objToAccess.name`? I think your requirement doesn't make much sense. You should just flag the `name` property, not its children; if any children are accessed then convert the boolean into an object detailing which child properties were accessed.

Comment: @Bergi because only `propsAccessed.name.front` was is used, that's the whole difficulty with the problem.

Comment: @MattK: `objToAccess.name.first` are two property accesses, not one - it's `(objToAccess.name).first`, accessing the parent object and accessing the child object. Of course, you can record those separately, and then find out after the call whether only one of them happened.

Comment: @Bergi lets say the function called `objToAccess.name` AND `objToAccess.name.first`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Proxy:

```
function isObject(val) {
  return val === Object(val);
}
function detectAccess(obj) {
  if(!isObject(obj)) return {proxy: obj, accessLog: true};
  var subProxies = Object.create(null);
  var accessLog = Object.create(null);
  var proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
      if(!accessLog[prop]) {
        var recur = detectAccess(obj[prop]);
        accessLog[prop] = recur.accessLog;
        return subProxies[prop] = recur.proxy;
      } else {
        return subProxies[prop];
      }
    }
  });
  return {proxy, accessLog};
}
var {proxy, accessLog} = detectAccess(objToAccess);
accessFn(proxy);
accessLog; // {id:true, name:{first:true}, address:{}}
```

The `accessLog` tells which properties have been accessed. If the value is a primitive, the log will contain `true`, otherwise it will contain an object.

Then, if you want to know for example if `objToAccess.address.street.name` has been accessed, use

```
!!(accessLog.address && accessLog.address.street && accessLog.address.name)
```

(see [test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/1529630) to avoid repeating all the property path).

If you want to consider that all the subtree has been accessed when a property of the top object has been accessed, just use

```
!!(accessLog.address)
```

Comment: this is *almost* right. The only place it fails is if a parent is accessed AND its child. For example: `objToAccess.name` and then `objToAccess.name.first`.  would yield `accessLog.name.first = true`, but `last` would also need to be true. Thank you for getting me in the right direction!

Comment: @MattK If you want to consider both `.name.first` and `.name.last` as accessed when you use `proxy.name`, then you only need to check `accessLog.name`.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but accessing `.name.first` + `.name` returns the same value as accessing just `.name.first`. In the former case, I'd need to also flag `.name.last` as true, but in the latter, `.name.last` should be false.

Comment: @MattK You are right. But when you access `.name.first`, you are first accessing `.name` under the hood. That's why there is no difference between `.name.first` + `.name` and `.name.first`.

Comment: yep, that's the part that still has me stumped. I think i need to return a `childAccessed` prop & if that comes back false then iterate through all the childProps & give them a `true`. Still haven't figured out how to do that though...